# NodeJS chat server example code

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, chat

I want to create a chat module for my web application. I searched on http://search.npmjs.org/ for "chat" and found many chat modules but none of them have any solid example tutorial that how can I implement my chat module.

Would someone provide a tutorial based on already created modules of NodeJS? I don't want to re-write the NodeJS server side code from scratch!

Comment: Can be closed under the official close reason: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam_.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

http://chat.nodejs.org/

Read the code, it's simple and clear! You can easily create the module yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link a simple chat example in step by step 
[node.js chat sever +client with out socket io](http://scriptime.blogspot.in/2014/04/a-simple-chat-application-using-nodejs.html)

Comment: If your answer can be resume with a link, make it like a comment